# jquery function on radio button checked not working

Tags: jquery, radio-button

my radio button in html :

```
    <input type='radio' name='sample' id='dynamic' value=dynamic          required='true'>
```

my jquery function for radio button :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:radio").on("click", function() 
    {
        alert('hieeee');
    });
    });
```

its not properly working
I have also tried for following code

```
    $('input:radio[name="sample"]').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
       alert('hieee');
    }
    });
```

but both the functions not working for me

Comment: Your code should work. Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: have you included jQuery in your page? check browser console for any error?

Comment: `its not properly working` which means??? And if it is a dynamic element (`id='dynamic'`?!), you should delegate event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
 $('input:radio[name="postage"]').change(
function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'Yes') {
        // append goes here
    }
});
Or, the above - again - using a little less superfluous jQuery:

$('input:radio[name="postage"]').change(
function(){
    if (this.checked && this.value == 'Yes') {
        // note that, as per comments, the 'changed'
        // <input> will *always* be checked, as the change
        // event only fires on checking an <input>, not
        // on un-checking it.
        // append goes here
    }
});
```